# Kill only one Java process by grep

Tags: process, java, kill

I want to kill this process:

```
root       11870 30.1 21.9 2358848 220980 pts/0  Tl   07:51   0:24 java -jar /opt/bonansa/bonansa.jar
```

If I do :

```
root@localhost:/usr/local/bin# ps -A |grep java
  11870 pts/0    00:00:24 java
```

I get the process, but I don't get the process if I do

```
root@localhost:/usr/local/bin# ps -A |grep bonansa.jar
root@localhost:/usr/local/bin#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first `ps` command where you see `/opt/bonansa/bonansa.jar` is something like `ps aux` or `ps -ef` where it it does full-format listing and returns the command in its entirety being used in addition to much more.

`ps -A` doesn't return all of this which is why the pipe into `grep` doesn't return anything.

If you just want to kill the process based on the string "bonansa" in the full command then you can use:

```
pkill -f bonansa
```